# How to keep 3 radio buttons in mvc 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i have one Field Called Address Type.

AddressType

[image]

i want to keep same as like which is mentioned in the below image

Address Type Radio Button

[image]

I keep this AddressType Field as DropDown . it contain totally 3 values and the data is fetch from AddressType Table. Now I want to change this dropdown to 3 radio buttons and depend upon selection in radio button i want to show div. How to do this in MVC4?

I have tried

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model =>model.AddressType,"Billing",true)  
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model =>model.AddressType,"Tax",false) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model =>model.AddressType,"Delivery",false)
```

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Please write what have you tried.

Comment: Html.RadioButtonFor(model =>model.AddressType,"Billing",true) Billing
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model =>model.AddressType,"Tax",false) Tax 
               @Html.RadioButtonFor(model =>model.AddressType,"Delivery",false) Delivery i gave as like this but it showing error

Comment: _but it showing error_ - What error?

Comment: Please specify Error detail

Comment: Actually its say the Delivery is not valid and also the id  for the particular value is not saved in the table

Comment: @Swetha, Based on your last comment it suggests property `AddressType` is a complex object. You cant bind a `string` to a complex object. You need to show you model(s).

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, get the address type from the database, where Id and AddressName are coloumn of the table AddressType, if you are using entity framework database first approach then see in the property names of the entity generated for table AddressType.

```
ViewBag.AddressType  = new SelectList(db.AddressType.ToList(), "Id", "AddressName");
```

In your view itrate each Address type with loop, make sure the name of the input field should be same when you gonna post it any controller action or use strongly type binding.

```
  @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.AddressType)
    {
       @item.AddressName <input type="radio" name="AddressType" value="@item.Id" />
    }
```